# Can't manage to call mojarra.ab(this,evt,'action',false,false,false);

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2.2

I'm trying to get rid of the inline javascript that mojarra creates to use the header x-content-security-policy. It's a header that disable inline script.

In order to do so I add a class to a button called **jsfajax** and I basically add an onclickevent listener to element which wear that class. I then call in mojarra.ab in that event listener. However the source parameter is null and I think that is why I can't get to the method in my bean.

HTTP request FORM DATA :

```
j_idt240:j_idt240
javax.faces.ViewState:-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx3:xxxxxxxxxxxx7022321
javax.faces.source:
javax.faces.partial.event:click
javax.faces.partial.execute:j_idt240:j_idt241 
javax.faces.behavior.event:action
javax.faces.partial.ajax:true



<h:commandButton styleClass="jsfajax" value="go" action="#{test.sayHi}">
```

JS:

```
var es = doc.getElementsByClassName('jsfajax');
    for(var i = 0; i < es.length; i++){
        myjsf(i, es);
    }
});

function myjsf(i , es){
    var e = es[i];
    e.onclick = function(evt){
        log(this); // outputs the button so I don't understand + jsf.ajax.request doesn't throw error
        mojarra.ab(this,evt,'action',0,0);
        return false;
    }
}
```

So the request is sent but it never reaches the action method.

However this does (and the source is the btn):

```
<h:commandButton value="go2" action="#{test.sayHi}">
   <f:ajax/>
</h:commandButton>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of request() there is :

```
var sendRequest = function() {
    var ajaxEngine = new AjaxEngine(context);
    ajaxEngine.setupArguments(args);
    ajaxEngine.queryString = viewState;
    ajaxEngine.context.onevent = onevent;
    ajaxEngine.context.onerror = onerror;
    ajaxEngine.context.sourceid = element.id;
    ajaxEngine.context.render = args[namingContainerId + "javax.faces.partial.render"];
    ajaxEngine.sendRequest();
```

It was because when adding the `<f:ajax>` tag the container adds an ID to the element - which kinda makes sens when it's a direct form submit the id is not needed when there is no f:ajax, thus not going through request()- . Which wasn't found in jsf.ajax.request.

So I just did this :

```
e.onclick = function(evt, e){
    this.id = this.name;
    mojarra.ab(this,evt,'action',0,0);
    return false;
}
```

I'm not sure if that can cause any issue though. Else I'll just put id in my button.